# I have a distorted signal and want to achieve a perfect wave in the output. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

I've been told to use a digital filter, but this solution achieves what I've been told to do.
It is so simple it is dumb, what am I missing here? I want to be more scientific about it.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Set the amplitude of the signal
amplitude = 220

# Set the frequency of the signal
frequency = 60.0

# Calculate the period of the signal
period = 1 / frequency

# Create an array of time values from 0 to 4 times the period with a step of 0.0001
time = np.arange(0, 4 * period, 0.0001)

# Generate a sinusoidal signal using the given amplitude, frequency, and time values
signal = amplitude * np.sin(2 * np.pi * frequency * time)

# Calculate harmonic components for the signal with different frequencies
h2 = (amplitude / 2) * np.sin(2 * np.pi * 2 * frequency * time)
h3 = (amplitude / 3) * np.sin(2 * np.pi * 3 * frequency * time)
h4 = (amplitude / 4) * np.sin(2 * np.pi * 4 * frequency * time)
h6 = (amplitude / 6) * np.sin(2 * np.pi * 6 * frequency * time)
h8 = (amplitude / 8) * np.sin(2 * np.pi * 8 * frequency * time)

# Combine the original signal with its harmonic components
signal_with_harmonics = signal + h2 + h3 + h4 + h6 + h8

# Extract the harmonic component from the signal
harmonic = signal_with_harmonics - signal

# Apply a filter to the signal by removing the harmonic component
filtered_signal = signal_with_harmonics - harmonic

# Create a plot for the signal with harmonics
ax = plt.axes()
plt.title("Signal with Harmonics")
plt.plot(time, signal_with_harmonics, c="red")
plt.yticks(np.arange(-400, 400, 100))
plt.xlabel("Time(s)")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude(v)")
plt.show()

# Create a plot for the harmonic component
ax = plt.axes()
plt.title("Harmonic Component")
plt.plot(time, harmonic, c="red")
plt.yticks(np.arange(-400, 400, 100))
plt.xlabel("Time(s)")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude(v)")
plt.show()

# Create a plot for the signal with the harmonic component removed (filtered signal)
ax = plt.axes()
plt.title("Signal with Filter")
plt.plot(time, filtered_signal, c="black")
plt.yticks(np.arange(-400, 400, 100))
plt.xlabel("Time(s)")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude(v)")
plt.show()
```

Comment: you're subtracting the harmonics, because you know the harmonics, including their exact amplitude and phase. From where would a receiver of `signal_with_harmonics` know them? Or, if they knew them, why would it have to reconstruct the sine wave? it could just as well generate its own sine wave and ignore the received `signal_with_harmonics` altogether.

Comment: a) you are not applying a digital filter, you are just adding and subtracting harmonics. b) you plot into three different axes but they are all siting on tip of each other. Use subplot() or plot everything into the same axes. c) other than that your code is fine, why do you think it's wrong?